# Determining Alphanumerics using char?

Tags: java, char, uppercase, alphanumeric

I have start letter Q and end letter K.

I want to increment like this:

```
Q,R,S,T...Z,0,1,2,3...9,A,B,C...K
```

I've tried:

```
        char start = 'Q';
        char end = 'K';

        while (start != end) {
            if((Character.isLetter(start) && Character.isUpperCase(start)) || (Character.isDigit(start))) {
                System.out.println(start);
            }
            start++
        }
```

This prints Chinese characters and so and so...

```
Â
ĕ
ƻ
```

I only want upper-case letters and numbers.
A-Z,0-9

I've also tried:

```
    if ((Character.getNumericValue(start) >= 10 && Character.getNumericValue(start) <= 35) 
&& Character.isUpperCase(start)|| (Character.getNumericValue(start) >= 0 &&  Character.getNumericValue(start) <= 9))
```

but again special chars and numbers are printed.

Comment: it's not a big array to declare. And it's pretty readable too!

Comment: What are you saying, that I should create a char array with letters and numbers and compare the start to that?

Comment: sorry, I may have misunderstood. You want to generate the sequence or do you want the sequence to use as a reference to increment something? (like, Z+1 = ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
char start = 'Q';
char end = 'K';
char stopHere = end++;

while ( start != stopHere ){
    System.out.println(start);
    if( start == 'Z' ){
        start = '0';
    }
    else if( start == '9' ){
        start = 'A';
    }
    else{
        start++;
    }
}
```

This is not the best answer but this will work it out.

Comment: I have to create the correct stopper to end exactly at 'K'.

Comment: If you think this is the best answer, please mark it as such. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks to Leo I done it this way:

```
char[] charArray = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L'
                            ,'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X',
                            'Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        char start = 'Q';
        char end = 'K';

        while (start != end+1) {
            for (int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++) {
                if(start == charArray[i]) {
                    System.out.println(start);
                }
            }
            start++;
        }
```

Comment: Looking at memory consumption's perspective, this is not so ideal. You are creating an array of characters which will eat up a little bit of memory. However, this is acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this -> end+1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Commons Lang, try this:

`if (CharUtils.isAsciiAlphaUpper(start) && CharUtils.isAsciiNumeric(start)) {...}`

Comment: I am not sure this is what @Eggy is looking for